# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given” error while trying to create a php shopping cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481963/warning-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given)

```
<?php
//connect to MYSQL
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
          die ('cannot connect:'.mysql_error());
}

//to show the original message
mysql_select_db("tracking", $con);

$result = "SELECT lat, lng, DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%W %M %D, %Y %T') AS datetime FROM markers1 WHERE 1";
if (!$result) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>id No</th>
<th>lat Time</th>
<th>lng</th>
<th>datetime</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lat'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lng'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['datetime'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
```

It show me  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.

Can anyone help me .thx.

Comment: you did not do `mysql_query($result)` before fetching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not running the query, it's only being stored in a string called $result.  Here is the function you need: http://php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually making a query...

Make the line...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT lat, lng, DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%W %M %D, %Y %T') AS datetime FROM markers1 WHERE 1");
```

Comment: Thx Jacob. May god bless u.hv a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mysql_query` to execute the query string. You also have a number of other problems with your code (the least of which is parameter binding.)

Answer (score 0):

try this `$result = mysql_query( "SELECT lat, lng FROM markers1 WHERE 1" );`

You need to call the `mysql_query()` function first before you can call any fetch function such as `mysql_fetch_array()`